# dask groupby agg weighted average "unknown aggregate lambda" error

Tags: python, dask

In Dask, I need to calculate the weighted average from grouping values of two columns, based on a third column. I am doing this:

```
dask_df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions = 10)
wm = lambda x: np.average(x, weights=dask_df.loc[x.index,"C"])
dask_df = dask_df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg({'C' : 
wm}).reset_index()
output_df = dask_df.compute()
```

In Pandas, I run out of memory.
In Dask, I get:

```
  File "<ipython-input-16-0beb32700c04>", line 3, in <module>
    dask_df = dask_df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg({'C' : wm}).reset_index()

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py", line 1555, in agg
    return self.aggregate(arg, split_every=split_every, split_out=split_out)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py", line 1550, in aggregate
    arg, split_every=split_every, split_out=split_out

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py", line 1355, in aggregate
    chunk_funcs, aggregate_funcs, finalizers = _build_agg_args(spec)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py", line 659, in _build_agg_args
    impls = _build_agg_args_single(result_column, func, input_column)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py", line 703, in _build_agg_args_single
    raise ValueError("unknown aggregate {}".format(func))

ValueError: unknown aggregate lambda
```

Comment: Do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in custom aggregations, as defined here: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-groupby.html#aggregate

Clearly that error message could be improved though.  I recommend raising an issue https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new