# How to group items according to a specific column so that I can use it in association rule model?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I need to group this rows as one row according to "Receipt No_"

| Item No_ | Receipt No_ |
| --- | --- |
| 101870 | 00000P2811000047666 |
| 102595 | 00000P2811000047666 |
| 102675 | 00000P2811000047666 |
| 101870 | 00000P2811000047666 |
| 189203 | 00000P2811000047666 |
| 300482 | 00000P2811000047666 |
| 325969 | 00000P2811000047670 |
| 351767 | 00000P2811000047670 |

1. 101870 102595 102675 105139

I want to have itemsets so that I can use it inside association rule model, I want to have a row like this:

| 101870 | 102595 | 102675 | 105139 | 110736 | 111139 | 122787 | 122787 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 356897 | 356897 | 102675 | 105139 | 110736 | 111139 | 122787 | 122787 |

Comment: Is it possible you include this as  data we can reproduce, not just a picture?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.groupby` to work this out. After you have make a dataframe `df`:

```
  Item No_          Receipt No_
0   101870  00000P2811000047666
1   102595  00000P2811000047666
2   102675  00000P2811000047666
3   101870  00000P2811000047666
4   189203  00000P2811000047666
5   300482  00000P2811000047666
6   325969  00000P2811000047670
7   351767  00000P2811000047670
```

You can group it, followed by `agg`.

```
list1 = lambda x : x.tolist()

new_df = df.groupby(['Receipt No_']).agg({"Item No_":list1})
```

You will get this:

```
                                                             Item No_
Receipt No_                                                          
00000P2811000047666  [101870, 102595, 102675, 101870, 189203, 300482]
00000P2811000047670                                  [325969, 351767]
```

To extract the list of items, just iterate over it:

```
for row in range(len(new_df)):
    print (new_df["Item No_"][row])
```

Comment: thanks Kevin for ur answer but, I wanna show u my code and what I got :                                                   # import required modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from dask import dataframe as df1

# time taken to read data
s_time_dask = time.time()
dask_df = df1.read_csv('Book.csv')
e_time_dask = time.time()


list1 = lambda x : x.tolist()

new_df = dask_df.groupby(['Receipt No_']).agg({"Item No_":list1})

for row in range(len(new_df)):
    print("Item No_ is : ", new_df["Item No_"][row])

print(new_df.head(10))

Comment: My error when I'm running this script :   ` ValueError(f"unknown aggregate {func}")
ValueError: unknown aggregate lambda`

Comment: You can check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57712143/16836078. Apparently, there's no `agg` in dask dataframe but you can always try this https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-groupby.html#aggregate